# Using typescript in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

here is my code

```
/// <reference path="typings/node/node.d.ts"/>

var net = require('net');
var x:net.net.Socket;
```

I wanna declare variable `x` as type `Socket`,but an error is reported
**TS2503: cannot find namespace net**

this is a portion of node.d.ts

```
declare module "net" {
    import stream = require("stream");

    export interface Socket extends stream.Duplex {
        // Extended base methods
        write(buffer: Buffer): boolean;
        write(buffer: Buffer, cb?: Function): boolean;
        write(str: string, cb?: Function): boolean;
        write(str: string, encoding?: string, cb?: Function): boolean;
        write(str: string, encoding?: string, fd?: string): boolean;

        connect(port: number, host?: string, connectionListener?: Function): void;
        connect(path: string, connectionListener?: Function): void;
        bufferSize: number;
        setEncoding(encoding?: string): void;
        write(data: any, encoding?: string, callback?: Function): void;
        destroy(): void;
        pause(): void;
        resume(): void;
        setTimeout(timeout: number, callback?: Function): void;
        setNoDelay(noDelay?: boolean): void;
        setKeepAlive(enable?: boolean, initialDelay?: number): void;
        address(): { port: number; family: string; address: string; };
        unref(): void;
        ref(): void;
```

Comment: Did you try to rename the `net` var to something else (like `var netService = require('net');`) and use the `Socket` interface of the module `net` with `var x: net.Socket;`?

Comment: @Brunt yes,the problem is still here

Comment: Take a look at the `typeof` keyword as described in [TypeScript Handbook: Optional Module Loading and Other Advanced Loading Scenarios](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#modules-optional-module-loading-and-other-advanced-loading-scenarios)

Comment: import Net = require("net");
var x: Net.Socket;

Comment: @MaxBrodin oh, it works, thanks for your help

Answer (score 4):

In TypeScript 1.5+:

```ts
import * as net from 'net';

let mySocket: net.Socket;
```

Or

```ts
import { Socket } from 'net';

let mySocket: Socket;
```